# Upload TestNg reports to S3

Tags: java, testng

I am currently looking into the ability to upload testng reports to Amazon S3 after test suite execution, based on parameters in the testng xml. Consider the following testng xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Base Framework Unit Test Suite" verbose="1" >
    <parameter name="upload-test-reports" value="true" />
    <parameter name="aws-provider-type" value="profile" />
    <parameter name="aws-s3-bucket" value="qa-reports" />
    <parameter name="target-reports-directory" value="TestProduct/Sprint1" />

    <test name="Test-base-built Unit Tests" >
        <parameter name="test-run-type" value="local" />
        <parameter name="name" value="Test-base-built Unit Tests" />
        <parameter name="browser" value="htmlunitwithjs" />
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="unittest" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="unittest.TestBaseBuilt_Test" />
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

Given the first four parameters (upload-test-reports, aws-provider-type, aws-s3-bucket, and target-reports-directory), the Java project will upload all files in the default test output directory (which is currently /build/reports/tests) to S3.

Now, the upload part is working fine for me. The problem is that it always uploads the files from the previous test run. I have tried creating a testng listener extending TestListenerAdapter and putting the upload logic in the onFinish method. That didn't work; it uploaded before the current run's reports generated. I also tried to write a custom testng reporter implementing IReporter and putting the upload logic in the generateReport method. Same result; it uploaded before the current run's reports generated.

So, do any testng experts out there know where I can put my file upload logic so that it executes AFTER testng actually generates the report files?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this ended up being a TestNG listener after all. I implemented IExecutionListener and put my upload logic in the onExecutionFinish method. This method ran after TestNG generated reports, so it uploaded the current test run's reports instead of the previous one.

Comment: Can you please provide some info how all these steps were implemented by you, like upload to s3 and generate report. I have a similar work, if you have github link or some tutorial or blog links that will be great. Thanks